# What do the symbols mean when running the command service --status-all?

Tags: linux

I ran the command service --status-all and it returned a list of what appear to be running services however what does each of the symbols `+, -, ?` mean. I had a look at the man pages but there is nothing that specifies what they mean. Attached is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[ + ]` started
`[ - ]` stopped
`[ ? ]` unknown

Source: [This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9995333&postcount=5) of [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1574977).

Comment: Thanks however what does `unkwown` refer to and why does it have the state of `unkwown`?

Comment: According to the linked thread, `services --status-all` only knows the status of services started with "The old System-V style init way", while `sudo initctl list` will list those started with the "upstart" method. Testing shows, on Kubuntu, that there are some unknowns that don't appear on the `sudo initctl list`. Most do. I don't know any further than that.

Comment: Also note that some services (started and otherwise) might not appear unless you `sudo service --status-all`.